# Import old, odd format, text files into R

Tags: r, database, txt

I'm on a wild goose chase and I hope someone here can help me.  Someone at my institution had an old database program on mac that I believe was called "Panorama".  They exported a file from that as .txt quite a few years ago and recently tried to import it into the latest "PanoramaX" program I guess (I'm getting some of this secondhand) and weren't able to do it.  Also, I'm a pc guy and would be totally lost on mac.  So being the data nerd they turned to me to see if I could salvage their data.  I tend to use R to import other file sources and every option I've tried here didn't work: (though I'm sure I missed an option maybe)

[image]

I can't share the file because it has personally identifying info, but a screenshot of what it looks like in notepad may help:

[image]

Does anyone have any experience with these files?  Or can tell what the delimiters are etc... so I could open it?

Comment: I wish you luck -- it can be difficult enough to find a way to parse a file, the complexity of that file is compounded by dealing with just an image of it. I hope somebody is able to visually recognize if for you. (As an alternative, while I'm generally not a fan of links to files, if you're able to provide a URL to the file, you might get some more feedback.) Good luck!

Comment: Absolutely, I would love to share a link.  I didn't yet because there are names/etc..  in there but I just asked the other people involved in the project if I could share it, because I do assume that'd be more helpful.

Comment: Yes, proprietary data and PII are good things to resolve before posting ... the internet never forgets.

Comment: The file looks like it has a ton of encoding issues. I would start by trying to read in the lines of the file and see what kind of encoding you are dealing with. Notepad is the absolute worst tool for this because it will automatically converts everything into a weird Windows encoding no one else uses (never accidentally save). Try if `stringi::stri_read_lines()` produces anything halfway readable.

Comment: Panorama X can only import databases that have been previously saved in Panorama 6. If you are still using an earlier version of Panorama, you will need to first open and save your database in Panorama 6 before it can be imported into Panorama X. Panorama X will display an error message if you attempt to open a database that was saved with Panorama 5.5 or earlier. [source](https://www.provue.com/panoramax/help/importing6tox.html)

Comment: I had just now read that a second ago, is there a way to import it using something else?  R? I have no access to any version of panorama

Comment: @JBGruber  Sorry I just saw your comment.  Just tried stringi::stri_read_lines("PLME.txt") and I got the error: Error in stri_encode(txt, encoding, "UTF-8") : embedded nul in string: ''

Any ideas?

Comment: The suggestion in `stringi` is: `f <- rawToChar(readBin('test.txt', 'raw', 100000))` then `stri_enc_detect(f)`. I haven't done this in a while but I remember that somehow `stringi` was pretty good with this stuff.

Comment: @JBGruber  similar problem.  Did f <- rawToChar(readBin('PLME.txt', 'raw', 100000)) and got "Error in rawToChar(readBin("PLME.txt", "raw", 1e+05)) : embedded nul in string:" prior to being able to do the str_enc_detect.    Thank you for all your help so far